# Limit of $\ln⁡(1+2x^2 )/\ln⁡(x^4+3)$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, limits-without-lhopital

I've tried finding the limit

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+2x^2)}{\ln(x^4+3)}$$

using L'Hôpital's rule and got $0$. My CAS says that the limit should be $\frac 12$. 
Can you please give me a hint on what to do?

Comment: Check your L'Hopital work...

Comment: What does $x$ tend to in the limit?

Comment: Sorry. Infinity.

Comment: I think you forgot to apply the chain rule when applying L'Hopital's rule. You should try adding your work in the post so that we can help you better identify where you made a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you mean $x\rightarrow\infty$.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{{\mathrm{\ln} \left(1+2x^2\right)\ }}{{\mathrm{\ln} \left(x^4+3\right)\ }}=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2\ln|x|+{\mathrm{\ln} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}+2\right)\ }}{4\ln|x|+{\mathrm{\ln} \left(1+\frac{3}{x^4}\right)\ }}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Actually, $x\rightarrow\infty$ it's $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Repeatedly rearrange and drop terms that become irrelevant in the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2x^2 + 1)}{\ln(x^4+3)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(2x^2 )}{\ln(x^4)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\ln(x) + \ln(2)}{4\ln(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2\ln(x)}{4\ln(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[\ln(1+2x^2)]=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[1+2x^2]\cdot\frac{1}{1+2x^2}=\frac{4x}{1+2x^2}$$
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[\ln(x^4+3)]=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}[x^4+3]\cdot\frac{1}{x^4+3}=\frac{4x^3}{x^4+3}$$

Then $$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(1+2x^2)}{\ln(x^4+3)}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{4x}{1+2x^2}}{\frac{4x^3}{x^4+3}}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4x}{1+2x^2}\frac{x^4+3}{4x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{4x}{4x^3}\frac{x^4+3}{1+2x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{x^4+3}{1+2x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x^4+3}{2x^4+x^2}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1+\frac{3}{x^4}}{2+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{3}{x^4})}{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}(2+\frac{1}{x^2})}=\frac{1+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3}{x^4}}{2+\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}}=\frac{1}{2}$$

(There are better ways to tackle this problem as shown by the other answers, but this is how you correctly do it with L'Hopital)

Answer (score 1):

As often, using *equivalents* makes things simpler:

- $2x^2+1\sim_\infty 2x^2$, so $\;\ln(2x^2+1)\sim_\infty\ln(2x^2)=\ln 2+2\ln x\sim_\infty2\ln x$,
- $x^4+3\sim_\infty x^4$, so $\;\ln(x^4+3)\sim_\infty 4\ln x$,
  and finally
  $$\frac{\ln(2x^2+1)}{\ln(x^4+3)}\sim_\infty\frac{2\ln x}{4\ln x}=\frac12.$$